# datetime grouping problem in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I can't seem to get my head around this, any help would be greatly appreciated:
I have a list of datetime nodes, grouped *by day* (for-each-group),

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="response/result/doc" 
group-by="functx:day-of-week(xs:dateTime(./date[@name='ds_startshow']))">
```

This works fine, the datetimes are grouped by day of the week. The problem is that I need to include some datetime nodes of the *next* day to the current day. For example: I need to include saturday 0:15 to the friday "group" (the early hours belong to the previous day). So a single day stretches out to some some hours of the next morning. Basically, a *new* day starts at 2:00 instead of 0:00.
How would I accomplish a grouping like that with XSLT(2). Presumably I need to write a function to tackle this? Do I need to iterate over the days? Not sure about the best practice in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is take the actual time and subtract two hours, thus creating a virtual day boundary at 02:00, and then group by that.  This is untested, but you might try:

```
$x - xs:dayTimeDuration("PT2H")
```

where $x is the actual time.  The result is the actual time minus 2 hours, which you can then use to group by.

You might look at [this site](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/dates.html), which I found by googling for "xslt date arithmetic", and is where I found the syntax for `xs:dayTimeDuration()`